# malfromed url exception

Tags: java, android, http

I am getting malformed url exception for 
http://staging.squadrun.co/media/question_images/2013_Map_Vector_3.jpg

```
URL url = new URL(src);
HttpURLConnection ucon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
ucon.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
URL secondUrl = new URL(ucon.getHeaderField("Location"));


HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) secondUrl.openConnection();
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.connect();
InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
return myBitmap;
} catch (IOException e){
    Log.d("sg", "src" + src );
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Paste your full stacktrace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get a NullpointerException in this line:

```
URL secondUrl = new URL(ucon.getHeaderField("Location"));
```

because `ucon.getHeaderField("Location")`returns `null` and these NullpointerException is mapped to a `MalformedURLException`.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.MalformedURLException
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at Test.main(Test.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    ... 4 more
```